# How to vertical align this div

Tags: html, css

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/mGJtu/1/) is my actual code :

```
<div class="main_right_content">
    <div class="main_right_content_text">
        my text is here and could be as long as possible. for example I write this code some times : my text is here and could be as long as possible. for example I write this code some times : my text is here and could be as long as possible. for example I write this code some times
    </div>

    <a class="main_right_content_link" href="#">Go</a>
</div>
```

And I'd like, when I minimize the window, put the link "go" in the middle about vertical align. In fact it stay always in top.

How can I do this with css(2)?

Comment: You want this to happen when you *minimize the window*?

Comment: I think he means "reduce the width of the window". A poor choice of words.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my english....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position: relative` on the container `div` combined with `position: absolute;     right: 0; top: 50%; margin-top: -<height/2>px` on the link.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/mGJtu/22/

Answer (score 1):

This Solution Matched me perfectly. Even if it is a link or just a text inside the div, this CSS Class could vertically align the content inside the DIV

```
 .verticalCenterDivText{
        height: 29px;
        line-height: 29px;
    }
```

Comment: That's an excellent technique for one line of text.    However, this is no good for the OP.